11/51 cassette with sgs deore m5100rd on state all road 4130
Would love to have a second opinion if it is a good idea for me to do it, I currently have a state all road 4130 med with Deore m5100 with a 1x gravel crank.

Can you clarify what you want. Are you wanting to change from the 11–42 to the 11-51?

Yep, we need more information here. We cannot give a good answer for a question that does not give details and is clear on the specific question being asked. Please edit your question to provide those details and clarification.

(Note: the edit was to fix a spelling error on my Iphone)

So I have 11/51 and the M5100RD and I just installed it on my state all road 4130 with a 1x 42Tooth gravel crank and now I have second thoughts about doing that and would love a second opinion on the build If it will all work together. sorry my
editing keyboard just keeps having typing errors do to my online gaming short keys

I'll take a stab at providing some info prior to OP editing question to actually ask one.
The Deore RD-M5100 (Rear derailleur) is designed only for an 11 speed, 11-51 tooth cassette with a 1x front drivetrain.
To run a 2x front or a 1x front with an 11-42 tooth cassette (2x) or an 11-46 tooth cassette (1x), Shimano says to utilize the RD-M5120 rear derailleur.  Thus, if you're currently running the M5100 derailleur, you are confined to the 11-51 cassette.  This being a strict interpretation of the specs and compatibility Shimano provides for the M5100 & M5120.  I know from experience the M5100 will do fine in a 1x with an 11-46t cassette. Absolutely normal shifting. Adjusted the B-screw so that the tips of the 46 toothed
cassette cog aligned with the (51t) mark on the back of the derailleur cage.
